# Replace blank with zero in matrix in SSRS Report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I would like to replace the blank cell with '0' in my ssrs matrix.
I am having this expression below to calculate the sum:

```
Sum(Fields!Count_Number.Value)
```

Which expression can I use in this case?

Thanks,
Olivia

Comment: `=IIF(Sum(Fields!Count_Number.Value)=Nothing,0,Sum(Fields!Count_Number.Value))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the result of your current expression shows a blank (`Nothing`) then the following should work.

```
=IIF(
     IsNothing(Sum(Fields!Count_Number.Value)),
     0,
     Sum(Fields!Count_Number.Value)
     )
```